# Functions calling functions

Tags: python, function

The problem with this code is that if you input anything other than `"bob"` first, when you finally input `"bob"`, the main function will print `None` instead. Please run this code to fully understand what i'm having trouble with and to provide me some answers.

```
def main(name):
    print name

def x():
    name = raw_input()
    if name == "bob":
        return name
    else:
        print "error"
        x()

main(x())
```

Comment: This is happening because the call to `x()` in your code creates a recursion when `"bob"` is not entered. The function that pops off the call stack first your first incorrect input (not `"bob"`), in which case `x` returns nothing, or `None`. I would look into different ways of doing validation (use a `while` loop instead of using recursion here), this looks confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use recursion here. A simple `while` loop is sufficient.

```
def get_name_must_be_bob():
    while True:
        name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
        if name.lower() == "bob":   # "Bob", "BOB" also work...
            return name

        # `else` is not necessary, because the body of the `if` ended in `return`
        # (we can only get here if name is not Bob)

        print "Are you sure you're not Bob? Try again."

def main():
    name = get_name_must_be_bob()
    print "Hello, " + name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not return a value in the "error" case. Change the `x()` to `return x()`